# Array of Char = Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

This is my method

```
private char[] listFindChar;
public void setlistFindChar(char letter){

int pos;
if (listFindChar !=null)
        {

            pos = listFindChar.length;
            pos ++;
            listFindChar[pos]=letter; 
        }
else{
  listFindChar[0] = letter; (cause problem)

}
```

Why the char is not add in the array of chars at the position[0]??

Thanks for helping me!!

Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the array, e.g.:

```
private char[] listFindChar = new char[100];
```

Otherwise, you just defined an array that is not initialized and points to some place throwing NullPointerExceptions at you for some reason...

Comment: Beat me by seconds.  This is exactly what's going on; if the space isn't initialized, then you'll be indexing into something that doesn't have anywhere to index into.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I notice you're not creating any space for the array.  You do so by specifying the space you want (i.e. if you wanted 30 chars, then you'd say `char listFindChar = new char[30]`).